# How does hair particle friction work?

Tags: particles

I am trying to get a collision and friction between hair particles but I couldn't find a way to do it. Can anybody help with these test files please?

[image]

[image]
Reference: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=17&v=1zdgV_oiJMU

Answer (score 1):

[![my result][1]][1]

1)The hairs can do hair self collisions only in the same hair particle system! In your example you have two hair systems

2)Internal friction has to be set to 0.2 - 0.8 range.

3) density target slider controls collision margin smaller values equal smaller collision distance. Be careful ! values set too low will cause hair explosions.[image]

4)Strength value (ALWAYS) has to be set to ((1)) unless you want interesting hair strands.

5) Voxel grid cell size optimal value 0.040

blendfile
[image]